# DRY - Typescript. How can I use DRY principles to avoid duplication of these 2 getters

Tags: javascript, typescript, dry, getter, typescript2.0

I know that below two getters are duplicates and could be consolidated and written in a better way. Could any one please help me come up with a way to consolidate these:-

isEqual here is a lodash library to compare two objects.
state in here is an injected state which I am picking the objects from.

```
   public get isUpperModified(): boolean {
        if (!this.isUpperAvailable) {
          return false;
        }
        if (
          (this.orders.upperPreference.type === '1' &&
            this.state.fetchedData.upperPreference.type === '1') ||
          (this.orders.upperPreference.type === 'UPPER' &&
            this.state.fetchedData.upperPreference.type === 'UPPER')
        ) {
          return false;
        }
        if (!isEqual(this.orders.upperPreference, this.state.fetchedData.upperPreference)) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }




public get isLowerModified(): boolean {
        if (!this.isLowerAvailable) {
          return false;
        }
        if (
          (this.orders.lowerPreference.type === '1' &&
            this.state.fetchedData.lowerPreference.type === '1') ||
          (this.orders.lowerPreference.type === 'LOWER' &&
            this.state.fetchedData.lowerPreference.type === 'LOWER')
        ) {
          return false;
        }
        if (!isEqual(this.orders.lowerPreference, this.state.fetchedData.lowerPreference)) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
```

Comment: can you please also show the calls to these methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than 1 way to achieve this.

You can create a new function `isModified(type: string)` and pass `upper` or `lower` as an argument.

Hope this helps

```
public get isUpperModified(): boolean {
    return this.isModified('upper');
}


public get isLowerModified(): boolean {
    return this.isModified('lower');
}

private isModified(type: 'lower' | 'upper'): boolean {

    const available = type === 'lower' ? this.isLowerAvailable : this.isUpperAvailable;
    const order = type === 'lower' ? this.orders.lowerPreference : this.orders.upperPreference;
    const state = type === 'lower' ? this.state.fetchedData.lowerPreference : this.state.fetchedData.upperPreference;

    if (!available) {
       return false;
    }

    if (
        (order.type === '1' &&
            state.type === '1') ||
        (order.type === type.toUpperCase() &&
            state.type === type.toUpperCase())
    ) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!isEqual(order, state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. did you mean "private modified" instead of private "get" modified. Because a getter cannot accept parameters.

Comment: Ah sorry :) No `get` should be there.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it something like this

```
public get isModified(type: 'lower' | 'upper'): boolean {
        const isAvailable = type === "lower" ? this.isLowerAvailable : this.isUpperAvailable
        const preference = type === "lower" ? "lowerPreference" : "upperPreference";
        if (!isAvailable) {
          return false;
        }
        if (
          (this.orders[preference].type === '1' &&
            this.state.fetchedData[preference].type === '1') ||
          (this.orders[preference].type === 'LOWER' &&
            this.state.fetchedData[preference].type === 'LOWER')
        ) {
          return false;
        }
        if (!isEqual(this.orders[preference], this.state.fetchedData[preference])) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
```

Then while calling this method

use `isModified("upper")` instead of `isUpperModified`

and

use `isModified("lower")` instead of `isLowerModified`